# Issue with Deleting rows from my second Table in my page

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a Reports page with 2 tables, one show items in stock the other shows Items sold.
I made a delete option for them which provides a button at the right end side of the table to delete rows out of my table.
The Issue that I am having is that the Code works perfectly for the 1st table but for the second table, the code will execute but the data does not get deleted from the DB.

I think what is happening is that due to me using the same Code to delete from both tables, that only 1 works. ( I think I am not sure)
After looking at it for a while trying to find potential errors I made and trying to see what else might be the issue, I decided to ask u for help!

Here the code:

```
<?php


$config['conn'] = array(
'host' => 'localhost',
'username' => 'root',
'password' => '',
'dbname' => 'inventarisdb'
);

$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $config['conn']['host'] . ';dbname=' . $config['conn']['dbname'], $config['conn']['username'], $config['conn']['password']);


$action = isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action']: "";

if($action=='delete'){ //if the user clicked ok, run our delete query
    try {

        $query = "DELETE FROM BCD WHERE id = ?";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $_GET['id']);

        $result = $stmt->execute();
        echo "<div>Record was deleted.</div>";

    }catch(PDOException $exception){ //to handle error
        echo "Error: " . $exception->getMessage();
    }

}

//select all data
$query = "SELECT ID, Categorie, SerieNummer, MacAdress, ProductCode, Prijs, RekNummer, PaletNummer, Hoeveelheid, Aantekeningen FROM BCD";
$stmt = $conn->prepare( $query );
$stmt->execute();

//this is how to get number of rows returned
$num = $stmt->rowCount();



if($num>0){ //check if more than 0 record found

    echo "<table border='1'>";//start table

        //creating our table heading
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<th>Categorie</th>";
            echo "<th>SerieNummer</th>";
            echo "<th>MacAdress</th>";
            echo "<th>ProductCode</th>";
            echo "<th>Prijs</th>";
            echo "<th>RekNummer</th>";
            echo "<th>PaletNummer</th>";
            echo "<th>Hoeveelheid</th>";
            echo "<th>Aantekeningen</th>";
        echo "</tr>";

        //retrieve our table contents
        //fetch() is faster than fetchAll()
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            //extract row
            //this will make $row['firstname'] to
            //just $firstname only
            extract($row);

            //creating new table row per record
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>{$Categorie}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$SerieNummer}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$MacAdress}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$ProductCode}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$Prijs}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$RekNummer}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$PaletNummer}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$Hoeveelheid}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$Aantekeningen}</td>";
                echo "<td>";


                    //we will use this links on next part of this post
                    echo "<a href='#' onclick='delete_user( {$ID} );'>Delete</a>";
                echo "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }

    echo "</table>";//end table

}else{ //if no records found
    echo "No records found.";
}

?>

<script type='text/javascript'>

    function delete_user( id ){
        var answer = confirm('Are you sure?');
        if ( answer ){ //if user clicked ok
            //redirect to url with action as delete and id to the record to be deleted
            window.location = 'Remove.php?action=delete&id=' + id;
        }
    }
</script>

<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>



<?php


$config['conn'] = array(
'host' => 'localhost',
'username' => 'root',
'password' => '',
'dbname' => 'inventarisdb2'
);

$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $config['conn']['host'] . ';dbname=' . $config['conn']['dbname'], $config['conn']['username'], $config['conn']['password']);


$action = isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action']: "";

if($action=='delete'){ //if the user clicked ok, run our delete query
    try {

        $query = "DELETE FROM CDE WHERE id = ?";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $_GET['id']);

        $result = $stmt->execute();
        echo "<div>Record was deleted.</div>";

    }catch(PDOException $exception){ //to handle error
        echo "Error: " . $exception->getMessage();
    }

}

//select all data
$query = "SELECT ID2, Klant, Categorie1, SerieNummer1, MacAdress1, ProductCode1, Prijs1, Hoeveelheid1, Aantekeningen1 FROM CDE";
$stmt = $conn->prepare( $query );
$stmt->execute();

//this is how to get number of rows returned
$num = $stmt->rowCount();



if($num>0){ //check if more than 0 record found

    echo "<table border='1'>";//start table

        //creating our table heading
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<th>Klant</th>";
            echo "<th>Categorie1</th>";
            echo "<th>SerieNummer1</th>";
            echo "<th>MacAdress1</th>";
            echo "<th>ProductCode1</th>";
            echo "<th>Prijs1</th>";
            echo "<th>Hoeveelheid1</th>";
            echo "<th>Aantekeningen1</th>";
        echo "</tr>";

        //retrieve our table contents
        //fetch() is faster than fetchAll()
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            //extract row
            //this will make $row['firstname'] to
            //just $firstname only
            extract($row);

            //creating new table row per record
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>{$Klant}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$Categorie1}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$SerieNummer1}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$MacAdress1}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$ProductCode1}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$Prijs1}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$Hoeveelheid1}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$Aantekeningen1}</td>";
                echo "<td>";

                    //we will use this links on next part of this post
                    echo "<a href='#' onclick='delete_user( {$ID2} );'>Delete</a>";
                echo "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }

    echo "</table>";//end table

}else{ //if no records found
    echo "No records found.";
}

?>

<script type='text/javascript'>

    function delete_user( id ){
        var answer = confirm('Are you sure?');
        if ( answer ){ //if user clicked ok
            //redirect to url with action as delete and id to the record to be deleted
            window.location = 'Remove.php?action=delete&id=' + id;
        }
    }
</script>
```

So in short: 1st Table: everything works, all data gets deleted
             2nd Table: Appears to be working but after confirming the Delete, the data is still there and didn't get removed from my DB.

The Code for Table 2 is exactly the same as the code for Table 1 exepct for the Names of DB and Table etc.

I am hoping you can go over my code see if you notice anything that might be causing this.
Maybe if u agree with what I was thinking, that the same code will not work for both tables on the same page, that you can give an example or a link to how I can tackle this issue?
Sorry for the Long code!
Thank you in advanced!

Comment: I think there is too much code in this question. Don't you expect use to read it all, do you?

Comment: I was afraid of that.. I can understand if u won't. I thought I put it all there not to miss out on anything that might be important but it's very long indeed xD Sorry!

Gonna try and re-edit to have only what's necessary!

Comment: I tried to edit and remove unnecessary Code.
The Code for Table 2 is exactly the same as the code for Table 1 exepct for the Names of DB and Table etc.
Hope you can help!
Thank you in advanced

Comment: I tried to run it using Fiddler but I am not really seeing what goes wrong. Could you maybe suggest a better Debugger that might give more insight to the user on where exactly something might be wrong?
I must say that I am not experienced programmer and I am trying my best to keep up with your Comments! But thank you so much for making effort and sharing this with me! Every little bit helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't mix the delete's because you might have an instance when one id be the same as the other, so you'll delete the wrong thing.  But I don't believe that is your primary problem:

Your select is

```
SELECT ID2, Klant, Categorie1, SerieNummer1, MacAdress1, ProductCode1, Prijs1, Hoeveelheid1, Aantekeningen1 FROM CDE
```

But your delete is:

```
DELETE FROM CDE WHERE id = ?";
```

You're delete should probably be:

```
DELETE FROM CDE WHERE ID2 = ?";
```

### To Prevent Deleting the wrong thing:

The easiest thing to do here, is change you're delete user JavaScript to accept an action parameter and specify which delete you want to perform, because both delete attempts are running right now.

**JavaScript**

You don't need the JavaScript twice on the same page.  Just have it one time in your `HEAD` or right before the end of the body.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function delete_user( action, id ){
        var answer = confirm('Are you sure?');
        if ( answer ){ //if user clicked ok
            //redirect to url with action as delete and id to the record to be deleted
            window.location = 'Remove.php?action=' + action + '&id=' + id;
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Checking Action**

```
if ($action=='delete_BCD') { 
// or
if ($action=='delete_CDE') {
```

**Rendering Rows**

```
echo "<a href='#' onclick='delete_user( \"delete_BCD\", {$ID2} );'>Delete</a>";
// or
echo "<a href='#' onclick='delete_user( \"delete_CDE\", {$ID2} );'>Delete</a>";
```

Comment: Perfect! :) Thank you very Much Daniel Gimenez that was a bulls eye!
It's working just fine now :)

I am going to try and apply what u explained as well to try learn from it, regarding "To prevent deleting the wrong thing" .

THo I can't help to wonder: Since every row in each table has its own delete button behind it, and each Table has a different DB and DB column names, Is it even possible to delete the wrong thing with this Code then? :)

I will still try what you said no matter what! For my knowledge's sake :)

Thnx again!